# Keep dropdown search box visible by JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have expandable search box on toggle click. 
I want to change search box to appear on mouse toggle hover, so I changed JS code to this:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
     $(".search-toggle").hover(function() {
         $("#search-container").slideToggle('fast', function() {
             $(".search-toggle").toggleClass('active');
         });
     });
 });
```

But search box disappear immediately when mouse leave toogle - so I can't use search.

Comment: dont use toggle. use .slideDown() on hover and slideUp after the search is started.

Comment: Thanks you, .slideDown() is working. But Im not familiar with JS. Can you help with implementing .slideUP?

Comment: post your code in http://codepen.io/ or https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/gorem/yyma1egp/11/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like you asked.

For this to work properly you should have the hover button inside the searchbar container. also check the css i made changes to the opacity and also the width and padding of the searchbar in order to work.

```
var searchContainer = $("#search-container");
$(".search-toggle").hover(function () {
    searchContainer.slideDown('fast');
});

//hide when search button clicked
$('input[type=submit]').on('click', function(){
    searchContainer.slideUp('fast');
});

searchContainer.mouseleave(function(){
    searchContainer.slideUp();
});
```

[link to your code](https://jsfiddle.net/yyma1egp/15/)

Updated Answer:

[check here](http://%20jsfiddle.net/yyma1egp/22)

Comment: No, it isn't. Here is example what I'm looking for [WP theme](http://8theme.com/demo/royal/) Search box disappear when mouse is out of toggle.

Comment: oh  you wanted to hide on mouse out ok.

Comment: Thanks you. By "searchbar container" you mean .search-box-wrapper? If yes, there is conflict with display: none.

Comment: Still cant get it work. Search box disappear when mouse is out of the search box, its ok. But when mouse is over toggle and get out of toggle directly (without moving over search box) search box wont disappear.

Comment: try changing the elements with mouse over and play with it.

Comment: Im not realy good one in JS [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gorem/yyma1egp/18/) Can you help me to finish it?

Comment: I cannot, unitl I see your code. just paste your code in codepen or jsfiddle, save it and send the link.

Comment: The major drawback in your code is the search icon and the search bar is in different places. But if you see that wp theme example the are in the same container and also close to each other. So it works for them. Do you understand this?

Comment: Now I have added a new div with class search-row in order to contain both the search icon and the search bar. Now when the mouse leaves the search-row div then your search bar hides. also check the css. the padding is to give extra space when mouse leaves.  http://jsfiddle.net/yyma1egp/22/

Comment: Its cool, but is it possible done it without adding extra div (I can change only classes in php functions)?

Comment: arent they wrapped in a parent element then make use of it. Otherwise it is not possible.  If you think your question is answered, kindly accept my answer and vote up.